# Get specific container using lxc/lxd-list command

Tags: linux, lxc, linux-containers, lxd

When I run the following command: 
[image]

I get the following output: 
[image]

But I only want to get the container specified in the command not all of them.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use POSIX Extended Regular Expressions:

```
lxc list -c n '^ubuntu$'

+--------+
|  NAME  |
+--------+
| ubuntu |
+--------+
```

If you don't want the formatting just use the `--format csv` switch, which will output just `ubuntu`